# Expose WCF Endpoints with REST and SOAP using authentication with simplified configuration

Tags: wcf, rest, soap

As usual, trying to find good examples to do exactly what I want is proving difficult.

I've written a WCF Service in .NET 4.5 with simplified configuration, so I've got no services section in the configuration file.

I want to provide SOAP and REST APIs.  I also need to restrict access by username and password and I've written a class derived from UserNamePasswordValidator that handles this.

By importing the service reference into a desktop app I can call the service using this code:

```
var svc = new MyUserService.UserServiceClient();
svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "TestApp";
svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "******";
```

I expect to be able to call the service from Javascript using something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://domain.userservice.svc',
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(data){
  },
  data: requestData,
  headers: {
    User: "TestApp",
    Password: "********"
  }
});
```

Here's the config file so far, with the SOAP service working.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfig">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyAuthenticationModule.Security.WcfUsernameValidator, MyAuthenticationModule.Security" />
          <serviceCertificate findValue="TestSelfSigned" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeName="My" />
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig" />
  </protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

By blindly following examples from around the web I ended up with this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfig">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBindingJson">
        <security mode="None" />
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyAuthenticationModule.Security.WcfUsernameValidator, MyAuthenticationModule.Security" />
          <serviceCertificate findValue="TestSelfSigned" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeName="My" />
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="jsonEndpointBehaviour">
        <enableWebScript/>
      </behavior>
      <behavior name="poxEndpointBehaviour">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig" />
    <add scheme="httpJson" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingJson"/>
  </protocolMapping>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I don't think that I'm too far from it, but I know I'm not there.  Can someone finish of the configuration, or point me in the right direction?  What url will I need to call from JavaScript?

If I were to add a Web API to support the REST service then I could handle the cross origin issues by catching the request in Global.asax.  How will I handle cors in the WFC service.

And a bonus question... I wanted to test the username on my dev machine / password authentication without having to install a certificate and go to https, and apply https later on the deployed site, but this doesn't look possible.  Am I correct?

Thanks for helping...